# Encoding in dplyr Sql Queries

Tags: r, encoding, dplyr

I'm having problems with encoding in a dplyr generated Sql-Query. I can query the database (Oracle, connected to with odbc) and it returns Norwegian special characters æøå, but I can't use those characters in the dplyr query. This filter returns a tibble with no data:

```
t_stat_mdl %>%
  filter(KAAK == "D - Lærling ")
```

The extra blank space is actually intended, that's how it's stored in the database.

If I wrap the dplyr pipe in `dplyr::explain()` I get this message:

```
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM ("T_STAT_MEDLEMMER_GRUNNLAG") 
WHERE ("KAAK" = 'D - Lærling ')

Error: <SQL> 'EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM ("T_STAT_MEDLEMMER_GRUNNLAG") 
WHERE ("KAAK" = 'D - LÃ¦rling ')'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: HY000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00905: nøkkelord mangler
```

So something happens with the encoding that changes

> Lærling

to

> LÃ¦rling

when dplyr writes the SQL-query. Any idea on how I can make sure dplyr use the right encoding when generating the query?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set your script to proper encoding by running this line at the start:

```
eval(parse(filename, encoding= "x-IA5-Norwegian"))
```

Else you can set this encoding by going to "File" then selecting "Reopen with Encoding", select the checkbox "Show all encoding" and then select "x-IA5-Norwegian"